# Plugin Settings UI for saving an array of values

Tags: plugin-development, settings, user-interface

I'm making a plugin where I'd like a user to be able to add values to a list, then have that list saved as an array.  Are there any smart ways of doing this? My current solution is to have a `textarea`, then make values out of each line but that's not ideal at all. Does Craft already have a built-in UI pattern for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the EditableTable template component (i.e. the same UI component that Table fields use).

*Note that this will only work inside the Control Panel – not on the front end. The title of this question says ["Plugin settings"](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/plugin-settings), so I'm assuming that's your actual use case.*

Here's how:

```
{% import "_includes/forms" as forms %}

{{ forms.editableTableField({
    label: 'Some setting',
    instructions: 'Some instructions here',
    id: 'someSetting',
    name: 'someSetting',
    cols: [
        {
            heading : 'Some column',
            type: 'select',
            options: [{label: 'Foo', value: 'foo'}, {label: 'Bar', value: 'bar'}]
        },
        {
            heading : 'Some other column',
            type: 'singleline'
         },
    ],
    rows: settings['someSetting']
}) }}
```

As long as the setting you use with the table (`someSetting` in the example above) has `AttributeType::Mixed`, Craft will automatically handle serialization for you (the rows you input in the table will be stored as a simple JSON object in the database, just like Table fields are stored).

Note that each `column` entry can have a type of `singleline`, `multiline`, `number`, `select` or `checkbox`. If you don't declare a `type`, the column will render as a PlainText field.

Also note that the variable `settings` (which is passed to the `rows` parameter) refers to an array of your plugin's current settings – meaning you'll need to pass those to your `settings.html` template like this (the following method should go in your plugin's primary class):

```
public function getSettingsHtml ()
{
    return craft()->templates->render('yourpluginhandle/settings', array(
        'settings' => $this->getSettings(),
    ));
}
```

Of course, you can pass additional variables to the settings template – such as a pre-populated array of label/value pairs to use for any dropdown (select) fields inside the table.

If you're unfamiliar with Twig macros, I recommend taking a look at [the official docs on the subject](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html) (if only to understand the syntax used, and the `import` statement).

Also, [here's the source for the `editableTableField` macro](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/templates/_includes/forms/editableTable.html), which could prove useful.